# Regex.exec behaving different for different input

Tags: javascript, regex

For the following javascript method

```
function evalExpression(expression) {
        if (expression) {
            console.log('Before Expression: ' + expression)
            var pattern = new RegExp(/\[(\w+)\]/gi);
            result = pattern.exec(expression);
            while (result != null) {
                for (var index = 1; index < result.length; index++) {
                    var oldKey = result[index];
                    console.log('match:' + oldKey);
                    var replacer = 'UNDEF';
                    expression = expression.replace(oldKey, replacer);
                    console.log('After expression: ' + expression);
                }
                // Get the next match.
                result = pattern.exec(expression)
            }
        }
    }
```

when I pass the input as

`evalExpression("[RelationshipRefToEMID] != null ) && ([RelationshipRefToEMID] <>3448001");`

the iteration for `exec` **happens only once**.

but when i call it for

`evalExpression("[RelationshipRefToMID] != null ) && ([RelationshipRefToMID] <>3448001");`,

then the iteration **happens twice**.

***following is the result of each execution***.

```
Before Expression: [RelationshipRefToEMID] != null ) && ([RelationshipRefToEMID] <>3448001
match:RelationshipRefToEMID
After expression: [UNDEF] != null ) && ([RelationshipRefToEMID] <>3448001
```

---

```
Before Expression: [RelationshipRefToMID] != null ) && ([RelationshipRefToMID] <>3448001
match:RelationshipRefToMID
After expression: [UNDEF] != null ) && ([RelationshipRefToMID] <>3448001
match:RelationshipRefToMID
After expression: [UNDEF] != null ) && ([UNDEF] <>3448001
```

I have tried hard but i am not able to understand this behavior.

Thanks.

Comment: `exec` has internal counter  which changes every time you `exec`. read about it in [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec). it will be better than any answer here

Comment: It's usually cleaner to put the `.exec` in the `while`'s condition, i.e. `while (result = pattern.exec(expression)) {` also, make sure you `var result` somewhere first ;)

Comment: I thought RegExp constructor takes string arguments, so the `var pattern = new RegExp(/\[(\w+)\]/gi);` should be `var pattern = new RegExp('\[(\w+)\]', 'gi');`, but Imight be wrong, as that seems to work.

Comment: @minseong: http://es5.github.io/#x15.10.3.1 shows that it can handle receiving a RegExp object, though there seems to be no point here. He should just use the literal syntax.

Comment: PrerakK: I'm curious to know why you're using both `.exec()` and `.replace()`. Seems like you should just pass the regex to `.replace()`, and then use a replacer function for the replacement.

Comment: @squint,i may be wrong. The problem i started out was that i want to find all the literals within [] and then look for that string in  one my dictionary and then again replace the match with the value found in the dictionary. Hope i described it well. thanks

Comment: ...I think your issue is that you're shortening the string, but the regular expression doesn't know it, so when it naturally picks up where it left off, it's now beyond the first character in what would have been the next match. Since the second example is matching a shorter string, fewer characters are removed from the string, so the starting point is still before (or on) the next match.

Comment: @PrerakK: Yes, you can do that with `.replace` by passing a function as the second argument, and returning the new value.

Comment: @squint great. I understood it is behaving weird because after replace the index might change. i just checked and after replace the `result.lastIndex` is `undefined` Please can you post your answer for the method you suggested. i tried that in the afternoon but i was no where with my little knowledge of javascript

Comment: `result` doesn't hold the `lastIndex`. The regular expression object does, so it would be `pattern.lastIndex`. You can manually change its value when needed.

Comment: The question was closed, but the solution with `.replace()` would be `expression.replace(pattern, function(m, g1) { return dict[g1]; })`

Comment: @squint, thanks. i'll try and see if this works. would you mind if i ask you the question if i miss something and it does not work for me?

Comment: i replaced my replace call with 
`expression.replace(pattern, function (m, g1) { 
return 'UNDEF'; 
})`
assuming that the dict lookup would always give me string 'UNDEF' 
but i ended in a infinite loop.

Comment: following worked for me but i am not sure how `expr = expr.replace(/\[(\w+)\]/gi, function ($1) {
        return 'UNDEF';
    });`; did not use the` exec` as you suggested